# vertical alignment of text in horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, menu, vertical-alignment

I have a menu in which some of the links are one line and some 2.
I can't find a way to vertically align the text,
it sticks to the top.
Any ideas how to fix my code will be great.

the css:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
ul.menu {
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    float:left;
    display: table-row;   
}

ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    height: 99px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(191,232,108,1);

    }

ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
    height:99px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #371C1C;
    background : rgb(168,168,168);

    }

ul li a:hover {
    background: transparent none;
    color: #fff;
}

ul li.active a{
    color: #0f0;
    background:rgba(31,169,244,1);
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

The html, here i tried few ways to break the line:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>bla bla<br/> blabla bla</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Twitter bla<br/> blabla bla</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Twitter bla blabla bla</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Move:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

..into to the `A`-tag CSS declaration, and out of the `LI`.

In general you'll find that if you put all of the styling  (other than `display:` `position:` and `float:`) on the A-tag rather than the list you'll have fewer headaches overall.

See my tutorial, [I Love Lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: Great answer thanks, works perfectly. Loved the tutorial as well. you changed my life.

Comment: Hero post. Thanks bro.

Comment: Thanks for drawing me back to this. It happened to be a timely fix for what I was working on too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the line-height of your `a` tags the same height of your `li`'s

Comment: From my experiences, this solution don't work for menu item with 2 lines or more.

Comment: That maybe true, I just don't like using table styles outside of a table. Nothing wrong with it, it just breaks convention.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="midalign">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About Us a very long link </a></li>
        <li><a>Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

CSS code:
#midalign ul {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    list-style:none;
    height:100px;
}

#midalign li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    width:100px;
}
```